# Excel Pivot table: how to show and rearrange only some of the totals?

Tags: microsoft-excel, pivot-table

I have a table in Excel (from a PowerPivot source, not sure it's relevant) with these fields:
product, type, volume. Type can be only A or B.

I need to create a pivot table that groups by product and shows these columns, in this order:

```
sum of volume for type = A
sum of volume for type = B
sum of volume for both types
avg volume for type A
avg volume for type B
max volume for type A
max volume for type B
```

I can do most of it with an ordinary pivot table, but:

- how can I remove 2 of the 3 totals? I don't need totals for avg and
  max, only for sum
- The totals are now appearing at the end. How do I move the sum total as per the order above?

I have made an example in the picture below; the totals are at the end. I need to move one total and remove the other two.

[image]

Thanks!

PS I could of course create a new table which gives me the order I need with a set of lookups, but I was hoping for a more straightforward solution.

Comment: Your question is quit confusing ! Like you have written "I don't need totals for avg and max, only for sum, The totals are now appearing at the end". On one hand you don't need the Totals but at other side you bothers why Totals are not appearing !! Better upload the Screen shot of PT, what you have made and what you need. Meanwhile I can say you need some Calculated Fields for Average & Maximum.

Comment: I have added a screenshot to explain what I'm after. The averages are not weighted, so I'm not sure why I'd need a calculated field.